# Blacklist globally: https://lmddgtfy.net/*

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, blocklist

Please blacklist lmddgtfy.net.

It should be blacklisted as the same reasons for Let Me Google That For YOu links.

It's shown up in comments on Ask Ubuntu lately, and should be blacklisted like LMGTFY.

Comment: You sure that this is widespread enough to be done network-wide?

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog given a single instance it's highly likely it'll be used elsewhere, and a single sighted occurrence of this type of link is still significant.  Idsagree with all of you who has closed it, since this request should be addressed by CMs and admins, *not* the SE community at large.

Comment: In that case, you should contact SE with a link to this request. Not that likely they'll act upon a single instance. The community is basically the gatekeeper of the SE team.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [quick check](https://www.google.com/search?q=lmddgtfy.net+site%3Astackoverflow.com+OR+site%3Astackexchange.com++OR+site%3Aaskubuntu.com+OR+site%3Aserverfault.com+OR+site%3Asuperuser.com&oq=lmddgtfy.net+site%3Astackoverflow.com+OR+site%3Astackexchange.com++OR+site%3Aaskubuntu.com+OR+site%3Aserverfault.com+OR+site%3Asuperuser.com) suggests maybe 17 extant uses across all of the network.

That's not really worth a blacklist - most of the entries will expire before they're ever hit, leaving us back in the same spot in a few months.

If it ever becomes a BIG problem anywhere, we can deal with it at that time.

#### Related: [Why is LMDDGTFY allowed while LMGTFY is not?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351381/why-is-lmddgtfy-allowed-while-lmgtfy-is-not)